# Way to ensure same jar versions across the projects in gradle?

Tags: java, git, gradle

We have 5-6 projects on github. They all should use the same versions of some libraries. What would be the best way to do so in gradle? Helpful is the fact that all developers have all the projects cloned in the same root folder.

### versions in the root

I can probably put versions in some property in the root folder and read from each projects `build.gradle`. However, this file then is not going to be on the github.

### versions in main project

one of the project is the main one, although it is not necessary to have it cloned. we can put definition there, but then everyone needs to clone this project just to use versions.

### versions in dedicated project

similar as above, but we can create a dedicated, developer-only project, that is containing versions definition, as well as maybe some developer-related stuff - maybe project documentation, to enforce the team to have it cloned?

... And it all has to work with IDEs ;)

Any experience?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which you prefer but an option is to place the version in a text file somewhere on the internet.  Then you can update the version as needed.

```
// inside your `build.gradle`
version "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/JBirdVegas/32520816ff79dd3928dd/raw/f8e6a0998a7a9b192750ad38b241ef99722c25fe/dynamic-version-test.txt".toURL().text
```

This example uses a gist which is versioned by a commit hash so it would require you to update the url for all the projects but you could just as easily make this a text file somewhere else.

This will work with any IDE that is building using the gradle files.

Comment: I have problem downloading it, as it asks for authenticating the request. Gists is not on the repo, so it would not work.